# Issue after using netrw in normal mode

Tags: netrw

I'm not sure what's causing this, but on MacOS 13.5/vim 9.0, after entering netrw via :Ex, :Sex, or :Vex and switching between files, upon entering the file, I'm unable to press shift+o or o to insert a line and enter insert mode; instead I get the following netrw message:

[image: netrw output]

I'm unable to use vim in normal mode (specifically shift+o and o) unless I :q out and reopen the file. This occurs about 75% of the time I use netrw, and as far as I can tell, I'm not pressing any accidental keys.

Never had an issue with this in the past. Does anyone have any insight as to what's going on here?

Comment: It looks like Netrw's normal mode mapping are leaking. You should open an issue if upgrading to the latest Vim and latest Netrw doesn't fix anything.

Comment: In the meantime, when this happens please show the result of `:map o` and `:map O`. If they show mappings to netrw stuff, you can probably `:nunmap o` and `:nunmap O` to fix it temporarily.

Comment: Both are returning "No mapping found"

Comment: Attempting to upgrade my packages now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Upgrading didn't work. Another point to add, is that when using :Vex or :Sex, netrw opens in both the file I already have open and a split tab.

Comment: @ThinkingInBits I also came across the :Vex and :Sex split tab problem. I wasn't able to reproduce that in a newer version of Vim on Debian so I imagine it's either a macOS issue or a Vim issue that has since been fixed.

Comment: Ok, turns out I didn't install vim with homebrew yet. I've just been using the 9.0 that came with this mac. So when I updated my packages, I assumed vim upgraded. Installed the latest minor version with homebrew, and so far it seems to be working. Fingers crossed!